# Working with section headers using NSFetchedResult controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I am new to core data and at the moment I am building a app with the core data model. What I want to achieve is a tableview divided with section headers for each month. At the moment I have the application working that it displays all the data in each cell, but without the section headers for each month. What I want is that the object with "date" : "26/08/2012" shows up below a section with title august.

I have a json webservice with the following data.

```
 "date": "26/08/2012",
    "hour": "18u00",
    "type": "JPL",
    "home": "KRC Genk",
    "away": "Zulte-Waregem",
    "homeScore": "2",
    "awayScore": "0"
```

I build an NSManagedObject subclass of it, and a category of this class to store the values inside the database. This all works.
For putting these values in the tableview I have the following method.

```
- (void)getKalender // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Kalender"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

}
```

And this is what I do in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"KalenderCell";

        KalenderCell *cell = (KalenderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass:KalenderCell.class]))
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KalenderCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // ask NSFetchedResultsController for the NSMO at the row in question
        Kalender *kalender = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Then configure the cell using it ...

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
       NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:kalender.date];
        cell.lblType.text           = kalender.type;
        cell.lblHome.text           = kalender.home;
        cell.lblHomeScore.text      = kalender.homeScore;
        cell.lblAwayScore.text      = kalender.awayScore;
        cell.lblAway.text           = kalender.away;
        cell.lblDate.text           = dateStr;
        cell.lblHour.text           = kalender.hour;


        return cell;
```

But here I am stuck. Can anybody help me how I can set those section headers using the NSFetchedResult controller ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you the same user as http://stackoverflow.com/users/965273/stef-geelen ? May I ask why you do not accept answers even if you definitely confirmed that they helped?

Comment: Yes I am the same user, but I wanted to start a clean profile. And don't I answer them by clicking the symbol on the right of your answer ?

Comment: You accept answers by clicking on the check mark symbol to the left of the answer. Im am talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782997/working-with-fetched-request-sort-descriptors/12783199#12783199, which you have not accepted yet. And I think there are also some of your older questions where you got a good answer which you did not accept.

Comment: Have a look at the [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple. It demonstrates how to group events into sections by year and month.

Comment: I tried to implement, but still things are going wrong. Please take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816049/working-with-a-nsfetchedresult-controller-and-section-headers-for-each-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the name of the field you want to use in the *sectionNameKeyPath* of your NSFetchedResultsController initial, like so:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];
```

This should set the date string as a section name. Feel free to use any field you want.